# Proof of $a<\frac{1}{a}<b<\frac{1}{b}$ by contradiction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am currently working on Velleman's *How to Prove It* section 3.2, question nine (question eight in the second edition).

Why does he hint in the solution section to go through the steps to first prove $a<1$ and $a<0$, rather than just using a proof by contradiction by assuming $a\ge-1$ to conclude the goal in one step? Can someone point out where I have gone wrong in this proof?

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are nonzero real numbers. Suppose $a<\frac{1}{a}<b<\frac{1}{b}$ and $a\ge-1$. Because $a$ is nonzero, either $a=-1$ or $a>0$. Clearly it is not the case that $a>0$ because this contradicts $a<\frac{1}{a}$. It cannot be the case that $a=-1$, as this also contradicts $a<\frac{1}{a}$. Therefore we conclude $a<-1$ as required.

EDIT: Right I can see the problem with my proof. The solution manual has this: "Suppose that $a\ge-1$. Dividing by the positive
number $−a$, we conclude that $−1\ge\frac{1}{a}$. Combining $a\ge-1$ and $−1\ge\frac{1}{a}$ we get $a\ge\frac{1}{a}$,
contradicting the fact that $a<\frac{1}{a}$. Therefore $a<−1$." Why can he divide by the "positive number" $-a$?

Comment: In the real numbers, $a\ge-1$ does not imply $a=-1$ or $a>0$ ($a=-\frac12$ is one counterexample).

Comment: Having $a>0$ doesn't contradict $a<\frac{1}{a}$. Take any number from interval $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are nonzero real numbers such that $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$. We want to show that $a < -1$.

To this end, suppose towards a contradiction that $a \geq -1$. Then there are three cases to consider:

**Case 1**: Suppose that $-1 \leq a < 0$. Then since $a$ is negative, we know that $-a$ is positive, so we can divide it from both sides of the inequality $-1 \leq a$ to obtain $\frac{1}{a} \leq -1$. But since $a < \frac{1}{a}$, it follows that $-1 \leq a < \frac{1}{a} \leq -1$ so that $-1 < -1$, a contradiction.

**Case 2**: Suppose that $a \geq 1$. Then since $a$ is positive, we can divide it from both sides of the inequality $1 \leq a$ to obtain $\frac{1}{a} \leq 1$. But since $a < \frac{1}{a}$, it follows that $1 \leq a < \frac{1}{a} \leq 1$ so that $1 < 1$, a contradiction.

**Case 3**: Suppose that $0 < a < 1$. Then since $a$ is positive, we can divide it from both sides of the inequality $a < 1$ to obtain $1 < \frac{1}{a}$. But since $\frac{1}{a} < b$, it follows that $1 < b$. Since $b$ is positive, we can divide it from both sides of this inequality to obtain $\frac{1}{b} < 1$. But since $1 < b < \frac{1}{b} < 1$, we conclude that $1 < 1$, a contradiction.

Thus, we conclude that $a < -1$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$